# what tools are good at making mathematic movies?

Tags: math-software

[here](http://tieba.baidu.com/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6/shipin/play/f8265eec832c78333a085c0d/) is a good math movie. what is your favorite software to make math movies? I used Mathematica, GeoGebra, Sketchpad. But they are not perfect. Also, could you recommend some interesting math movies?

Comment: @Jasper Loy. Thank you! It's movie!----what I want is shuxue dianying

Comment: I'm watching the movie Good Will Hunting

Comment: watched 10 minutes. I don't like Good Will Hunting.

Comment: Most of the movies that I made on my youtube channel had frame generators written in C and then thrown at mjpegtools to generate mpegs.

Comment: @deoxygerbe, let me have a look

Comment: @a boy: they're linked from my math.SE profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "perfect" software for making math visualization videos. The better movies of this kind were likely made using standard 3D animation software such as Cinema4D, Maya, 3d studio, XSI and such. You'll probably have to export data from a math application such as Mathematica into these suites and do the renderings in there. It's possible to render with just POV-Ray but working with a 3D suite can get you much better results.

Some examples:

1. Not Knot, [part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGLPbSMxSUM) and [part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKwAS5omW_w)
2. [Moebius Transformations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY)
3. Sphere Eversion [Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVVfs4zKrgk) and [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7d13SgqUXg)